# Anyone know how to access the magento gift card sku in transactional email template?

Tags: magento

I had a custom utility task that allowed users to choose an image to accompany the gift card notice that is sent to the recipient when a gift card is purchased at the magento run shop. In the template, there is an assortment of variables available so you can customize the email that is sent. However, in order to add the correct image, I need to have access to the gift card sku number since my method for handling this was to simply create many gift cards and apply separate images for each one, then use javascript to swap the sku numbers when the user clicks the images. Simple enough.

In the app/code/core/Enterprise/GiftCard/Model/Observer.php file, the variables are set:

```
                $templateData = array(
                    'name'                   => $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_recipient_name'),
                    'email'                  => $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_recipient_email'),
                    'sender_name_with_email' => $sender,
                    'sender_name'            => $senderName,
                    'gift_message'           => $item->getProductOptionByCode('giftcard_message'),
                    'giftcards'              => $codeList->toHtml(),
                    'balance'                => $balance,
                    'is_multiple_codes'      => 1 < $goodCodes,
                    'store'                  => $order->getStore(),
                    'store_name'             => $order->getStore()->getName(), // @deprecated after 1.4.0.0-beta1
                    'is_redeemable'          => $isRedeemable,
                );
```

So I could add the product sku to this array and it would be available in the template system. Problem is, I don't know where to trace this back to even know how to get the Sku. I assume it is somehow available in the $item var, but magento has no documentation on this particular case and I can't guess since there is no method for testing. The email script is activated when the card is purchased so I can't just click a "Send test" button to see what comes out in the email that is sent to the user. The preview button dismisses variables.

Anyone happen to know about this? Possibly something like $item->getSku()

Any input helps.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That snippet is from the method `Enterprise_GiftCard_Model_Observer::generateGiftCardAccounts()` which is registered as a handler for `sales_order_save_after` event. That event is passed the same 'order' object as the "new order placed" emails have. You can experiment by altering that email template and triggering a new email by resending from the order page in admin.

`$item->getSku()` is almost certainly right.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that. Since it is a live alteration I suppose I will have to spend some small amount to test. In the past this was expensive, since their refund system was not always in sync and somehow we'd have to go through this whole ordeal to refund. Never the less, if I can keep resending from an order history then that is awesome.

Comment: Create a free product long enough to make your order. Set it's visibility to none and add it through the admin. Being free you can use the "Zero Amount" payment method to avoid any cost to yourself.

Comment: Yup. $item->getSku() worked as you mentioned. The zero dollar item did not though. I was not able to add a zero dollar item to cart. So I just made my gift card min $.25. I was unable to find a way to resend the gift card notification though, so I had to do it twice. Got lucky. Sometimes it can be many many times before finding the right balance.

Comment: Sometimes when testing I use "Check" or "Purchase Order" payment method since it avoids real payment details. However it's hard to do that on a live store since others will see it if they checkout at the wrong time. At least you have it sorted now.